# Am I forced to use aliases in Hibernate queries?

Tags: java, sql, spring, database, hibernate

I bumped into an interesting issue. I am trying to select some entities from my DB. And I have a Hibernate as my ORM.
When I use query like that:

```
  TypedQuery<Notification> query = entityManager
            .createQuery(
                    "select Notification from Notification where Notification.user.userName = :username",
                    Notification.class);
```

It throws NullpointerException inside the Hibernate.
BUT if I just use the same query but with aliases it makes it work.
For example this works(notice the aliases):

```
TypedQuery<Notification> query = entityManager
        .createQuery(
                "select notification from Notification notification where notification.user.userName = :username",
                Notification.class);
```

So my answer is "Is it necessary to use aliases with hibernate ORM or otherwise it will not work?"
It is now important here how my entity looks like but if you will need it then I will edit my answer.

Comment: In order to refer to the Entity in other parts of the query, you will need to assign an alias [Ref 15.2](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: Note that it's usual to use short versions, so `Notification n` would make your query more compact without making it harder to understand.